# Normalization in the artificial neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, normalization

I am having problem to understand normalization concept in artificial neural networks. If you could explain how it works. For example if I want input basketball score 58-72 or if I want input word “cat” (as a natural language word). How it works if the range is [-1,1]. Be aware that I am very new with ANN and normalization concept.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to bit-encode your input; have one neuron per bit of the maximal length input string; and feed 0 as -1, and 1 as 1. If you desire a bit-string as output, then interpret positive outputs as 1 and negative outputs as 0.